# how do you have two buttons that save to the same data file in android?

Tags: java, android, onclick, textview, sharedpreferences

I have it set up so when you click one of the words it will add 10 points and the other will add 5 points but I want it to be typed out in the same textview, however im not sure how to do it because how I have it right now it wants me to change the settings and editor to "settings1" and "editor1" but if I do that it will no longer type the amount of points out in the "test" TextView. I hope I expaned it good enough, thanks for helping

heres my code

```
public class page1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

    TextView Q1A1;
    TextView Q1A2;
    TextView test;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final int testScore = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        Q1A1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A1);
        Q1A2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A2);
        Q1A1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Q1A2.setOnClickListener(this);
        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);




        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        test.setText(""+settings.getInt("YourScore", 0));


    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.Q1A1:

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("YourScore", (testScore + 10));
            editor.commit();

            //Intent FinalScore = new Intent(this, FinalScore.class);
            //startActivity(FinalScore);
            break;
        case R.id.Q1A2:

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("YourScore", (testScore + 5));
            editor.commit();

            break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case statements do not create a new scope, so you are declaring the variables settings and editor twice.

Your code in the two case statements are the exact same except for the number of points being added.  Why not create a method that has all the shared code.

```
private void addPoints(int points) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("YourScore", (testScore + points));
    editor.commit();       
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.Q1A1:
        addPoints(10);
        break;
    case R.id.Q1A2:
        addPoints(5);
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks works great!
would you happen to know how to have it so the TestScore is equal to the score you have?
what I have is
public static final int testScore = (""+settings.getInt("YourScore", 0)); 
but I get an error on the "settings"

Comment: @MichaelZeuner You don't have a settings object yet, so you cannot set the testScore.  Also you are trying to set an int to a string.  What you can do is make the variable non final and non static, and then set it in onCreate.

Comment: Im sorry if this is borthing you but Im not quite sure what you ment, did you say it should be a string and not an int? String testScore = (""+settings.getInt("YourScore", 0)); like that. also once I did that I know have an error on the testScore in the add points method

Comment: @MichaelZeuner No, it should be probably be an int, since you're using it as an int, but you're trying to assign a string to it.  int testScore = settings.getInt("YourScore", 0);  The "" + causes the result to be a string which cannot be assigned to an int.  Keep it as an int, and only convert to Strings when you are displaying to the user.